# JavaBeans JSP dealing with GET requests

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, javabeans

I understand how POST works but if for example the following GET request is made:

```
GET /index.jsp?page=home
```

How do I get the value, in this case home through to my java bean. i.e. using an MVC architecture?

Thanks

Comment: This question is really vague. Please elaborate *"How do I get get this in a MVC form".* If you include an example which works for POST the expected way, we may be able to understand the problem better.

Comment: You've updated the question, but I still don't see a problem. It should just work the same way as you do with POST. Either case, the parameters are just accessible the same way using JSP/Servlet API (`request.getParameter()` and so on). Please elaborate more. Preferably include a technical example which works for POST, but not for GET (in your specific case).

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of patterns to achieve this. My personal favorite is actually never to do GET or POST request on a jsp but always on a servlet. This servlet updates the beans, then forward the request to the adequate jsp. There's also a lot of frameworks seeking to simplify this process one way or another.